# Hierarchical outputs or output of empty list one by one without waiting to rest objects

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, ros

I create empty list and add name of detected objects to in it.

the output to new list every loop added one object and output it directly without waiting to finish adding

I just need the output all objects  as list output and disappear rest outputs

this my code:

```
import rospy
import numpy
import tf

from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
from sensor_msgs import point_cloud2 as pc2
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, PointCloud2
from dodo_detector.detection import SingleShotDetector
from dodo_detector_ros.msg import DetectedObject, DetectedObjectArray
import math

class Detector:

    def __init__(self):
        self._detector = SingleShotDetector('frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt', confidence=0.5)




        self._global_frame = rospy.get_param('~global_frame', None)
        self._tf_listener = tf.TransformListener()




        self._bridge = CvBridge()


        rospy.Subscriber("/camera/rgb/image_color", Image, self.image_callback)
        rospy.Subscriber('/camera/depth/points', PointCloud2, self.pc_callback)
        self._current_image = None
        self._current_pc = None


        self._imagepub = rospy.Publisher('~labeled_image', Image, queue_size=10)



        self._publishers = {None: (None, rospy.Publisher('~detected', DetectedObjectArray, queue_size=10))}




        self._tfpub = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
        rospy.loginfo('Ready to detect!')

    def image_callback(self, image):
        """Image callback"""

        self._current_image = image

    def pc_callback(self, pc):
        """Point cloud callback"""

        self._current_pc = pc

    def run(self):

        while not rospy.is_shutdown():

            if self._current_image is not None:
                try:


                    if self._global_frame is not None:
                        (trans, _) = self._tf_listener.lookupTransform('/' + self._global_frame, '/camera_link', rospy.Time(0))


                    scene = self._bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(self._current_image, 'rgb8')
                    marked_image, objects = self._detector.from_image(scene)  # detect objects
                    self._imagepub.publish(self._bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(marked_image, 'rgb8'))  # publish detection results


                    msgs = {}
                    for key in self._publishers:
                        msgs[key] = DetectedObjectArray()


                    my_tf_id = []
                    my_dis =[]
                    for obj_class in objects:

                        rospy.logdebug('Found ' + str(len(objects[obj_class])) + ' object(s) of type ' + obj_class)

                        for obj_type_index, coordinates in enumerate(objects[obj_class]):
#                     
                            rospy.logdebug('...' + obj_class + ' ' + str(obj_type_index) + ' at ' + str(coordinates))

                            ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = coordinates
                            y_center = ymax - ((ymax - ymin) / 2)
                            x_center = xmax - ((xmax - xmin) / 2)

                            detected_object = DetectedObject()
                            detected_object.type.data = obj_class
                            detected_object.image_x.data = xmin
                            detected_object.image_y.data = ymin
                            detected_object.image_width.data = xmax - xmin
                            detected_object.image_height.data = ymax - ymin


                            publish_tf = False
                            if self._current_pc is None:
                                rospy.loginfo('No point cloud information available to track current object in scene')


                            else:

                                pc_list = list(pc2.read_points(self._current_pc, skip_nans=True, field_names=('x', 'y', 'z'), uvs=[(x_center, y_center)]))

                                if len(pc_list) > 0:

                                    publish_tf = True

                                    tf_id = obj_class + '_' + str(obj_type_index)        #object_number

                                    my_tf_id.append(tf_id)
                                    print my_tf_id




                                    detected_object.tf_id.data = tf_id



                                    point_x, point_y, point_z = pc_list[0] #point_z = x, point_x = y



                            if publish_tf:


                                object_tf = [point_z, -point_x, -point_y]

                                frame = 'cam_asus_link'

                                if self._global_frame is not None:
                                    object_tf = numpy.array(trans) + object_tf

                                    frame = self._global_frame

                                self._tfpub.sendTransform((object_tf), tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, 0), rospy.Time.now(), tf_id, frame)

                except CvBridgeError as e:
                    print(e)
                except (tf.LookupException, tf.ConnectivityException, tf.ExtrapolationException) as e:
                    print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('dodo_detector_ros', log_level=rospy.INFO)

    try:
        Detector().run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        rospy.loginfo('Shutting down')
```

I used line 120

```
print my_tf_id
```

output:

```
[u'person_0']
[u'person_0', u'chair_0']
[u'person_0', u'chair_0', u'chair_1']
[u'person_0', u'chair_0', u'chair_1', u'book_0']
[u'person_0', u'chair_0', u'chair_1', u'book_0', u'book_1']
```

I just need this output:

```
[u'person_0', u'chair_0', u'chair_1', u'book_0', u'book_1']
```

and disappear those outputs:

```
[u'person_0']
[u'person_0', u'chair_0']
[u'person_0', u'chair_0', u'chair_1']
[u'person_0', u'chair_0', u'chair_1', u'book_0']
```

please help me

thank you in advance or some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Just to reiterate your question, you are creating a list on the fly and only want to display the last element you are adding. In general when asking a question like this, please create a simple example relevant to your question. No point adding complications from ROS, subcribers and callbacks etc. 
To your questions, here are a couple ways to handle this:

1. Print your reponse only after you finish your loop, this will print everything just once.
2. Print just the last element you added, `tf_id` in your case. If you want it on the same line you can use print statement as: `print(tf_id, end='', flush=True)`